# Conditional Formatting on Sum of Two Columns in Excel

Tags: excel, formatting, conditional-statements

I have two conditional formatting rules.  One highlights the minimum value of the column and works correctly (Column B).  I want to also highlight the adjacent columns within the same row (Columns D and E).  Columns D and E in the same row will always add up to the value in columns B.

Essentially, I need equivalent code to be put into the conditional formatting field that resembles this:

```
=($B$175=($D$175+$E$175)) AND $B$175=MIN($B$175:$B$190)
```

```
=SMALL($B$175:$B190,1)
```

This will incorrectly fill any item in column D that matches the minimum of column B.
[image: Results 1]

```
=SMALL($D$175:$E$190,COUNTIF($D$175:$E$190,0)+1)<br>
```

This will incorrectly fill the minimum of column between columns D and E.
[image: Results 2]

```
=$B$175=($D$175+$E$175) or <br>
```

=SMALL(($D$175:$D$190)+($E$175:$E$190), 1) 
This will incorrectly fill all rows of columns D and E.
[image: Results 3]

```
=$B$175=MIN(($D$175:$D$190)+($E$175:$E$190), 1)<br>
```

This will not fill any rows column between columns D and E.
[image: Results 4]

I know I'm close, but can't seem to figure it out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to check that the value in B is the SMALL of `$B$175:$B$190`. You don't need to consider the sum of E and F.

```
=$B175=SMALL($B$175:$B190,1)
```

[image]